# Passing static variables to a static jTextArea

Tags: java

good day. I need help getting this to work properly.

I had something in mind but im not sure how to do it.
if I can add the event listener to the class properly I might be able to make this work. right now the results comes up empty. this is a Radio Frequency RX/TX application im working on. i just need the received code to display on my jTextArea(ta1) which is also a static component.

```
import jssc.SerialPort;
import jssc.SerialPortEvent;
import jssc.SerialPortEventListener;
import jssc.SerialPortException;

public class TestRead extends javax.swing.JFrame implements SerialPortEventListener {
    static SerialPort serialPort;
    public String max;

    static class SerialPortReader implements SerialPortEventListener {
        @Override
        public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
            try {
                //System.out.print(serialPort.readString());
                max = serialPort.readString();
                ta1.setText(serialPort.readString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }

    static String getSE(String x) {
        System.out.println("Result: "+max);
        return x;
    }

    public TestRead() {
        initComponents();
    }

    //some netbeans generate code goes here..                                    

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        getSE("");
    }                                        

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        serialPort = new SerialPort("COM21");
        try {
            serialPort.openPort();//Open serial port
            serialPort.setParams(SerialPort.BAUDRATE_9600,
                    SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                    SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                    SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);//Set params. Also you can set params by this string: serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0);
            serialPort.writeBytes("\002v0\003".getBytes());//Write data to port
            serialPort.closePort();//Close serial port
        } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
            System.out.println("Serial set Verbose: " + ex);
        }
        try {
            serialPort.openPort();//Open port
            serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0);//Set params
            int mask = SerialPort.MASK_RXCHAR + SerialPort.MASK_CTS + SerialPort.MASK_DSR;//Prepare mask
            serialPort.setEventsMask(mask);//Set mask
            //Add SerialPortEventListener
        } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
            System.out.println("Serial Port SetMask: " + ex);
        }
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestRead().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

When I try to pass the value of the serialPort, into max, its empty. can anyone help?

im using JSSC.jar

Comment: Please learn about the difference between static "stuff" and normal fields. Basically using "static" should be a last resort; and it is not good practice in the first place. And we can't tell you what serialPort.readString() is doing ... unless you show us the code behind that.

Comment: `ta1.setText(serialPort.readString());` should be `ta1.setText(max);` if readString actually reads from and advances a buffer.

Comment: @rumpydumpy your code will not compile as it is written.  Can you confirm that you've posted legitimate code for the example ?

Comment: @adamdc78 tried that. it just remains blank.

Comment: @OYRM I had to truncate the code since what I just needed to show was the actual code I added to it. most of it is netbeans generated and are for configuring GUI. If you want I can post an uploaded file.

Comment: Understood, and reasonable, however, You removed one non-gui related block of code.  You seem to have two classes implementing `SerialPortEventListener`, one of which does not in fact implement the appropriate interface.  If your code cannot really be run, then it really is very difficult to tell what it is that you're trying to do.  With that in mind, a few words of clarification on the listener that you're actually trying to use would be helpful. `TestRead` or `SerialPortReader` ?  The listener hasn't been added to the port either.  Did you remove that code ?